# Google Analytics Url Limit

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any limit to the url that google analytics can track for utm parameters?

We have utm source, medium, campaign, term, content attached to the url, but something seems off. Someone said the limit was 255, which might be why we aren't able to track it, as our url is longer, but there is no mention of this in the google analytics doc.

So is there a limit to the url that I need to care about?

Thanks in advance
Pratik

Answer (score 2):

If utm_content is a URI, then the according to RFC 2616 they can be any length (however URIs over 255 bytes in length may cause issues for older browsers and proxies). In reality, most browsers can't process URIs over 2000 characters in length.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-in-the-utm-content-param-in-ga